# How to estimate $\sum_{x=1:n}{xf(x)}$ having $\tilde{f}$

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

I have an estimator $\tilde{f}(x)$ whose error is at most $\epsilon$, i.e., $\frac{|f(x)-\tilde{f}(x)|}{|f(x)|} \leq \epsilon$.

I want to estimate $\sum_{i=1:n}i.f(i)$ with a small error. But if I sum up the $\tilde{f}$ the error would be really high $n\epsilon$ which is not acceptable. Is there any solution for that?

Is this information enough or I should provide more information?

(*) Edit: What if the error is not fixed, i.e., $\Pr[\frac{|f(x)-\tilde{f}(x)|}{f(x)}>\epsilon] \leq \alpha$, what is the resulting probability of error? Is it $Pr[\frac{|\sum{xf(x)}-\sum{x\tilde{f}(x)}|}{\sum{xf(x)}}>\epsilon] \leq n\alpha$?

Comment: what is the form of $f(x)$, what is the expected value of $\epsilon$

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 We have a set $X$ and $map$ maps each element $x \in X$ to a subset, $map:X \rightarrow 2^X$; $f(x)$ is the size of corresponding subset produced by $map$.

Comment: OK, but the more important question is how is $\epsilon$ distributed? What is the form of the error? Is this a deterministic problem where you just know the truncation error? In that case, you may not have many options besides the "unacceptable" option.

Comment: The function $f$ is estimated using a  least element sampling of $map$. The $\epsilon$ is determined by the number of samples, the more samples, the less error.

Comment: Unfortunately, since you are trying to estimate a *sum*, knowing the magnitude of the relative error will not help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I sum up the $\tilde{f}$ the error would be really high $n\epsilon$...

No. Actually, using the fact that every $x$ is nonnegative, one gets:
$$(1-\varepsilon)f(\ )\leqslant\bar f(\ )\leqslant(1+\varepsilon)f(\ )\implies\frac1{1+\varepsilon}\sum_xx\bar f(x)\leqslant\sum_xxf(x)\leqslant\frac1{1-\varepsilon}\sum_xx\bar f(x)$$

Comment: Is this Hoeffding theorem?

Comment: No--only basic analysis.

Comment: So, you swapped $f$ and $\tilde{f}$, then multiplied them by $x$, which is fine; But I didn't mention in the question (my bad) that this error is not fixed. With some probability, we will get this error, so the problem arises in the probability of getting such low error, right?